# Easiest way in general to find the sin, cos, arcsin, arccos, of "not so easy" angles/values without using a calculator?

Tags: trigonometry

I was wondering if there are any easy ways in general to find the sin, cos, arcsin, arccos, of "not so easy" angles/values without using a calculator. By "not so easy" I mean just not things like 0, $\pi/6$, $\pi/4$, $\pi/3$, or $\pi/2$, which one encounters routinely. And also not $\sin(\theta+2n\pi)$, $\sin(n\pi)$, $\sin(-\theta)$, and the like. The reason I'm asking this terribly general question (please forgive me for that) is because in Calculus class I always make some sort of error when these sorts of calculations need to be done to solve a problem.

For example, on a recent question I had to find $0<\theta<2\pi$ satisfying $\sin\theta=-1/2$.

We know $\sin(\pi/6)=1/2$ and $\sin(-\pi/6)=-1/2$ since $-\sin(x)=\sin(-x)$. Also we know sin has period $2\pi$ so $\sin(-\pi/6+12\pi/6)=\sin(11\pi/6)$=$-1/2$.

But how would one get $\sin(7\pi/6)=-1/2$ for example?

Or similarly how would one know the value of sin $4\pi/3$, $5\pi/3$, $5\pi/4$, $6\pi/5$, $5\pi/6$, etc. Or cos, arcsin, arccos, of such "nasty" values?

Again, I apologize for the ridiculously general question, it's just that I know no other way of asking it.

Comment: Back in pre-computer times, they had big books of tables of values. Navigators at sea would look them up to do the calculations necessary to figure out position via location of the stars.

Comment: Also the [slide rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slide_rule) could be used for that.

Comment: **Sketch** a sine curve, a cosine curve, whatever is needed. You are familiar with "special angles" between $0$ degrees and $90$ degrees, and can use the pictures for the rest. So for example for $7\pi/6$, we are $\pi/6$ past $\pi$, the sine is negative, and has, from the shape of the curve, the same absolute value as $\sin(\pi/6)$.

Comment: You could use local linear approximation at "nice" angles for rough estimates of the nastier angles.

Comment: You could use a Taylor expansion of sine or cosine, but i don't know how convenient that is

Comment: You could approximate values using tables, graphing, identities and expansion. For example $cos(nx)$ can be expanded in terms of $cos(x)$ as in here:http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Multiple-AngleFormulas.html

Comment: See [trigonometric constants expressed in real radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_constants_expressed_in_real_radicals#Table_of_constants). Also, $\cos\bigg(\dfrac\pi2~x\bigg)\simeq\Big(1-x^2\Big)\bigg(1-\dfrac{x^2}{4.5}\bigg)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\pi/4$ is an angle of a $1:1:\sqrt{2}$ right-angled triangle, and $\pi/6$ and $\pi/3$ are angles of a $1:\sqrt{3}:2$ right-angled triangle, the $\sin / \cos / \tan$ of these and their multiples are easy to calculate on the fly.

$\sin 6\pi/5$  or something similar would be harder.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to easily calculate multiples of $\pi/6$, $\pi/4$, $\pi/3$, $\pi/2$? for example $7\pi/6$, $5\pi/3$, $5\pi/4$? That would me tremendously helpful.

Comment: $\sin (\pi - x) = \sin x$, $\sin (\pi + x) = - \sin x$,  $\cos (\pi - x)=-\cos x$,  $\cos (\pi + x)=-\cos x$, $\tan (\pi - x) = -\tan x$, $\tan (\pi + x) = \tan x$ will get you the rest

Answer (score 2):

For the simpler question (the only ones you'll have to deal with in introductory calculus classes) of how to figure out multiples of $\pi/6$ and $\pi/4$, imagine the angles as being created by points on a unit circle.

Now, find the coordinates of each point: if it's a multiple of $\pi/4$, you know that the side lengths of a right isosceles triangle are $1:1:\sqrt{2}$, and if it's a multiple of $\pi/6$, you know that the side lengths of half an equilateral triangle are $1:2:\sqrt{3}$.

Divide the y-coordinate by the x-coordinate and you have the tangent; divide the y-coordinate by the hypotenuse and you have sin; divide the x-coordinate by the hypotenuse and you have cos.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Lots of usage of various formula related to $\sin nx$ and $\cos nx$ and half-angle formulae.

For example, if $x=\pi/5$ then $0=\sin \pi = \sin 5x$. You can expand: $$\sin 5x= \sin x\left(16\cos^4 x - 12\cos^2 x+1\right)$$
So $y=\cos x$ is a root of $16y^4-12y^2+1=0$. We can solve for $y^2$ using the quadratic formula, then take the square root to get $y$. (You actually end up with four potential solutions, but you can see what they represent.)

In general, we know that $\sin(\pi +x)=-\sin(x)$ and $\cos(\pi +x)=-\cos(x)$. So you can always reduce the problem to $0\leq x<\pi$.

Use $\cos (A+B)=\cos A \cos B-\sin A\sin B$ to come up with a formula for $\cos nx$ and $\sin nx$. Look up [Chebyshev polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) if you want the advanced treatment.

Comment: Thank you for your answer sir. Pointing out that $\sin(\pi +x)=-\sin(x)$ and $\cos (A+B)=\cos A \cos B-\sin A\sin B$ was especially helpful.